# perl add contents of a column of a file

Tags: perl, addition

```
Column A            | Column B    | Column C       |  Column D
35627799100             8               8               2 
35627788000             60              34              45 
35627799200             10              21              21 
35627780000             60              5               8
```

Basically I have a file as shown above and would like to add the contents of Column B i.e 8+60+10+60. To be frank I'm not sure if need to remove the first line being text and if I can use the split function and put it in a hash something along the lines:

```
my %hash = map {split/\s+/,$_,4} <$file>;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sum up the second column, a hash is overkill. You can do something like this and calculate the sum directly in the map.

```
my $sum;
$sum += (split /\s+/, $_)[1] while <$file>;
```

**Edit:**  If you have header rows or other rows with non-numeric values in column 2, then as the comments below indicate, you will run into problems.  You can avoid this by trading `split` for a regular expression, like so:

```
my $sum = 0;

while (<STDIN>)
{
    $sum += $1 if $_ =~ /^\S+\s+(\d+)/;
}
```

If it's possible that column 1 has no text (ie. the line starts with a single blank and the first non-blank represents the second column), then change the first part of the pattern from `^\S+` to `^\S*`.

Comment: `$sum += (split ' ', $_, 3)[1] while <$file>` would be preferred: It doesn't read the whole file into memory, it accesses the correct column (array indices are zero-based) and it avoids splitting more than neccessary by limiting the number of resulting fragments to three. Btw, `map` in void context just means you wanted a `for`, and a  loop over a filehandle should normally use an iterator with `while`.

Comment: or `$sum += (split)[1] while <$file>` for shortness

Comment: You know what, I made a typo.  I meant `[1]` and not `[2]`, and even have that in the test script I have offline.  I'll edit the above to fix it.  But as for `map` vs. `while`, `map` should be just as lazy as `while`, shouldn't it?   *Edit:*  I just tried it, adding `say` in front of `$sum +=`, and `map` does slurp the whole file before processing.  I'll change the above to use `while`.

Comment: I tried it out and got an error: Argument "number" isn't numeric in addition (+) at ./bss_licence.pl line 7, <$file> line 1.

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum;
open my $file, "<", "LicenseCounters.log" or die($!);
$sum += (split ' ', $_, 3)[1] while <$file>;

Comment: If your input file has header rows or similar, then you'll have to add additional logic to skip those rows.  For example, change to a regexp inside the loop:  `while (<STDIN>)
{
    $sum += $1 if $_ =~ /^\S+\s+(\d+)/;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example based on your data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum_column_b = 0;
<DATA>; #drop header

while( my $line = <DATA>) {
    $line =~ m/\s+(\d+)/; #regexpr to catch second column values
    $sum_column_b += $1;
}
print $sum_column_b, "\n";  #<-- prints: 138


__DATA__
Column A            | Column B    | Column C       |  Column D
35627799100             8               8               2 
35627788000             60              34              45 
35627799200             10              21              21 
35627780000             60              5               8
```

Comment: would you kindly explain how $line =~ m/\s+(\d+)/; is catching the second column? Any in the line $sum_column_b += $1; why is $1 is used? Thanks

Comment: the first column doesn't have blank spaces ath left side. So the first match of the regexpr is the Column B: 1 or more spaces \s+ before the digits (\d+). I memorized it with parentheses at $1.

Comment: It'd perhaps be more robust to explicitly state `^\S+` at the start of the regexp to only match lines with that property, and to put the sum in the body of an `if` statement so you skip header lines explicitly.  In this case it may not matter much (empty string acts as zero), but to me it feels safer to be explicit.